# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects while running .fit() on RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, hyperparameters

I'm trying to run the model on RandomizedSearchCV to get the best hyper parameters

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(300, input_dim=7500, activation="relu"),
                                 keras.layers.Dense(300, activation = "relu", name = "Intermediate"),
                                 keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"),
                                 keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")])

keras_cls = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(model)
    
    
param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1, 300),
    "learning_rate": 1e-3
}

rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_cls, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3)
rnd_search_cv.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30,
                  validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                  callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

at  `rmd_search_cv.fit` I'm getting the error `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`

What should be done to correct the error?

Comment: Why do you expect that params `n_hidden` and `n_neurons` can be tuned by CV? How does your CV object know what are the corresponding parameters of the Keras model, since there are no such parameters in its definition?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I came across a similar implementation with KerasRegressor and thought if it can be done with a Classifier. Should I add anything to the code?

Comment: If you have seen it with Keras regressor, please post the link.

Comment: It's in the hands on machine learning book. I found the related github https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/10_neural_nets_with_keras.ipynb

It's under hyperparameter tuning section

Comment: You can see that there all 3 params `n_hidden`, `n_neurons`, and `learning_rate` are explicitly part of the model definition function `build_fn`, which is the recommended way of using the sklearn wrapper in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier); this is not the case with your code here. Why not starting from that point then? (You'll discover in the way that you cannot treat the *architecture* as a hyperparameter, but given the usage in the link, what you do here does not make sense).

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow it and then check again.

Comment: I tried the same code with classifier, changing the loss to categorical_crossentropy and optimizer to Adam and changing the input_dim but got the error 'RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x7f152fd28438>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter learning_rate'. Am I missing something?